# The relationship between prime divisor of the number of cyclic subgroups of order $2$ with prime divisor of a finite group

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group and $k$ be the number of cyclic subgroups of order $2$. Why is every prime divisor of $k$ a prime divisor of the order of $G$?

Comment: Consider $G$ acting on the **set** of order 2 subgroups via conjugation...

Comment: Of course, as soon as you show some work of your own.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I have misread your question.  What you're asking doesn't seem to be true, unless I am still misreading it.  Where is this problem from?

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample: $G={\mathbb Z}_2\times {\mathbb Z}_2\times H$, where $2$ and $3$ do not divide $|H|$.

Comment: Easier perhaps is $D_8$.

Comment: @Steve D: Yes, but OP could add an additional constraint: $G$ is not $2$-group. :-)